# Laravel кастомизация валидации

Tags: html, html5, laravel

Вопрос в следующем, как мне при выводе ошибки валидации указать свое название поля

```
    return Validator::make($data, [
      'hotel_name' => 'required|max:256',
      'hotel_description' => 'required|max:256',
      'number' => 'required',
      'star' => 'required',
      'food' => 'required'
    ]);
```

На выходе я получаю сообщение тип

```
Поле hotel name обязательно для заполнения.
```

а хотелось бы

```
Поле название отеля обязательно для заполнения.
```

Где указать кастомное название поля? заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Для этого лучше создать новый реквест и там переопределить метод с сообщениями:

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'required' => 'This field is required',
        'string' => 'The field must be a string',
        'numeric' => 'The field must be numeric',
        'unique' => 'The field must be unique',
        'reportdate' => 'The field must be a valid date',
        'in' => 'It can be one of the values: Рабочее время, Больничный, Отпуск, Отгул',
        'between' => 'The value must be between [:min - :max]',
    ];
}
```

Тексты ошибок можно также переопиределить и в контроллере. Здесь об этом можно почитать [введите сюда описание ссылки](https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/validation)

Comment: А каким либо образом переопределить имя поля есть возможность?

Answer (score 0):

Вы имеете в виду это, или что-то другое?

```
public function messages()
{
    return [
        'hotel_name.required' => 'Поле название отеля обязательно для заполнения.',
    ];
}
```

Comment: Не отвечайте второй раз. Просто отредактируйте свой первый ответ.